# Pass Argument to EventListener and Get keyCode

Tags: javascript

I suspect this is due to my lack of understanding of how keyCode information is passed but I cannot figure out how to make this work...

I need to get the keycode from a keydown event. I can manage to do the following easily enough:

```
document.getElementById("challenge").addEventListener("keydown", keyTest);

function keyTest(e) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
}
```

How do I pass an argument from the EventListener in addition to getting the keyCode from e. For example.

```
document.getElementById("challenge").addEventListener("keydown", keyTest, "The argument passed");

function keyTest(e, message) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
        alert(message);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass a parameter? What information would you need to give the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the only way to do it is this.

```
    document.getElementById("challenge")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
           keyTest(e, "the argument passed");
        });

    function keyTest(e, message) { 
       alert(e.keyCode);
       alert(message); 
    }
```